# Automation of SQL instance discovery notification

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I wanted to know if there is a way to get automated notification via mail when a new SQL instance is discovered in the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box solution for this one, but you can implement a windows service that keeps looking for instances endlessly, warning any interested party when a new one is found...
If you know how to program, it should not take you more than 10 min to do so...

**Edit1**
Turn up VS and create a new project. Select as a template "Windows Service".
Add the reference to the [SMOs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162189.aspx)
Use [GetDataSources()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources(v=vs.110).aspx) to find instances and store them on a list or whatever
Upon loop, check for new instances. new instance found? [SendMail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Comment: logic sounds to be simple, can u please help me out with coding if you are aware of it?